# preg_match lets an unwanted line slip through

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using preg_match to put conditions on the lines, to process, within a loop.
Here is my code:

```
$import = 'LT_VALUES2';
$contents = explode('-',$import,2);
$line = 'DATA LT_VALUES2 TYPE TABLE OF RGSB4 WITH HEADER LINE,';
if(preg_match('/(DATA $import)/i',$line) == 0 && preg_match("/($import\b|$contents[0]\W)/i",$line) == 1 && preg_match("/[']/",$import) == 0 && preg_match("/(\D)/",$import) == 1)
{
```

It reaches here for no reason

```
}
```

why it is failing to process the conditions I provided? I tested the same code at [phptester.net](http://phptester.net/) and it works the way I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quoted strings will not interpolate variables, which is probably what you're expecting it to do.

`'/(DATA $import)/i'` is literally `/(DATA $import)/i`.

On the other hand;

`"/(DATA $import)/i"` would interpolate to `/(DATA LT_VALUES2)/i`

Comment: Ok, but I have another line which causes the problems:

`$line = 'DATA LV_NUM TYPE N VALUE 01,';
$import = 'LV_NUM';
$contents = explode('-',$import,2);
if(preg_match("/(DATA $import)(?=\* value )/i",$line) == 0 && preg_match("/(DATA $import)/i",$line) == 1)
{
break;
}
elseif(preg_match("/(data $import)(?=\* value )/i",$line) == 1)
{
}`
In this case, it breaks the loop but it should not, do you think any problem with that?

Comment: @Adarsh I'm afraid I'm not even going to try and parse that comment.

Comment: Sorry, I m a newbie and don't know how to format it properly